# Kendo UI Combobox is not refreshing after submit clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, combobox, kendo-ui

I am trying to refresh kendo combobox fields after post method triggered.

But always combobox gets selected items after post.

Code is here:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(p => p.KurumKodu)
    .ValuePrimitive(true)
    .Name("KurumKodu")
    .DataTextField("HospitalName")
    .DataValueField("HospitalId")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 300px;margin-right:5px;", @class = "form-control" })
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .Placeholder("Kurum Seçiniz...")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetCascadeHospitals", "SptsCustom")
                .Data("filterHospitals");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .Enable(false)
    .AutoBind(false)
)
```

I tried this codes for refreshing

```
 $("#KurumKodu").data("kendoComboBox").input.val("");

 $("#KurumKodu").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.read();
```

But they don't help.

How can we solve this?

Thanks

Comment: try adding `cache : false` in read method,then call `datasource.read()`.

Comment: How can we do this in asp.net mvc razor?

Comment: Do you mean the combobox is showing the same selected items you chose before you submitted the form? In which case, show you controller methods.

Comment: Yes it is the issue.

Comment: try like this `source.Read(read => read.Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "Area" }).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))`

Comment: Then show your controller methods!